# How to create a gmail filter that can filter all emails that reference me

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

so I have created a filter that captures all emails that are addressed to me.
But lot of people put me in CC whereas it should be actually be addressed to me.
(eg when they are looping me in or FYI me **specifically in the body of the email**)

I want a separate filter that can capture all emails that can do that
what I have done is as Follows

`"Has the words"  +Allwyn OR @Allwyn OR +Allwyn.p OR @Allwyn.p OR +Allwyn Philip OR @Allwyn Philip.`

But the result ropes in everything even those that do not have the words in the body of email

for that i tried to use a negative of my email id with the above code
 `-allwyn.p@gmail.com`  this also did not work correctly.

can you point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance